# How to set constraints to stack views?

Tags: swift, autolayout, stackview

I’m trying to achieve this layout using the interface builder
[image]

I’ve already tried to embedded the bottom button inside another stackview, also tried to set it out of the stack view but nothing works as expected what have now is this[image]
And getting this result[image]

**Can someone tell me what constraints are missing or what is wrong with my current constraints?**

Comment: Do you want your buttons to be **Round**? Or, six **Oval** and a **Round** button centered at the bottom?

Comment: the shape must be round for all buttons, but I fixed that with scale `aspectFit`. The problem is when I turn to landscape the layout is not like the first image. @DonMag

Comment: And do you want all your buttons to be `64 x 64`, regardless of orientation?

Comment: Only the one at the bottom should be `64 x 64`

Comment: How do you want to size the other buttons? As large as will fit? A percentage?

Comment: As large as will fit, no problem with that.

Comment: OK - a little tough to guess what you really want, but is this about it? https://imgur.com/a/SHoCS5c

Comment: Yes this what I want to achieve. I've already achieve it , I'm not sure if I achieve it using the best practices. But I did it https://imgur.com/a/g88h6yK

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't need to add too many constraints to the stack view's arranged subviews. Setting the distribution and alignment correctly is the key. The constraints involving Stop Button are either unnecessary or causing the conflict that you see in the console.

To position the stack view, you just need to pin its top, bottom, leading, trailing edges to the safe area. For example:

[image]

Then, set the alignment of all the stack views to "Fill", and the distribution of all the stack views to "Fill Equally".

Comment: I just tried what you suggest me, but seems that something is missing now, I don't where to accommodate the last button in the view hierarchy. This is the behavior I'm having now.